# WP7: Where do I get calendar, phone book and tabs Application Bar icons?

Tags: windows-phone-7, icons, application-bar

I found the Application Bar icons in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.0\Icons, but this folder does not contain the following standard icons:

- button that shows the month view in the calendar
- button that switches to contacts in phone
- button that opens tabs in Internet Explorer

I want to stick to the WP7 look and feel, so where can I find these icons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is unclear to me why Microsoft did not include all icons in the icon pack. Pedro Lamas acquired a bigger collection of icons from some binary files. The collection is available on his blog: http://www.pedrolamas.com/2011/03/12/wp7-application-bar-icons/ I hope it contains the icons you need.

I don't know what you plan on doing with the application you are building, but keep in mind that using icons obtained from a binary might not be fully legal.

**Update:**
On his blog Templarian is also sharing a lot of designs for WP7 icons, a very useful addition to the existing collection. He's also taking suggestions through twitter for new designs. Check out his icon collection with over 100 icons [here](http://templarian.com/project_windows_phone_icons/)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [MetroStation Icon Pack](http://www.iconspedia.com/pack/metrostation-3025/) as well, and the [NounProject](http://thenounproject.com)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this will have everything you need, but this is the icon pack i've used: http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/03/27/windows-phone-7-series-icon-pack.aspx

Comment: Thes icons are the same as the ones mentioned in the question.